# NullPointerException while adding "addinline" function in mimemessage

Tags: java, spring, email, nullpointerexception, email-attachments

500 error - nested exception is org.springframework.mail.MailPreparationException: Could not prepare mail; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

I am trying to generate emails using smtp server.I am able to generate emails without adding inlne image whereas when I  add "addinline" function I am getting nullpointer error in the output screen and not able to generate emails,images are not been fetched from the system.I am getting same error when I am trying to send attachments.Thnaks in advance.

in dao implementation

```
@Autowired
private JavaMailSender mailSender;


mailSender.send(new MimeMessagePreparator() {
        public void prepare(MimeMessage mimeMessage) throws MessagingException, IOException {
    MimeMessageHelper message = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, true, "UTF-8");
    message.setFrom(from);
    message.setTo(recipientAddress);
    message.setSubject("Subject");
        message.setText("<html><body><img src=\"cid:identifier1234\"/></body></html>", true);
        FileSystemResource res = new FileSystemResource(new File("D:\images\photo.svg.png"));
            message.addInline("identifier1234", res);
     }
    });
```

Bean class in xml

```
<bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
    <property name="host" value="smtp.com" />
    <property name="port" value="25" />

     <property name="username" value="Sender.email@abc.com" /> 
    <property name="password" value="password@123" />
    <property name="javaMailProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="mail.transport.protocol">smtp</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

error in output window

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [welcome] in context with path [/registrationForm] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.mail.MailPreparationException: Could not prepare mail; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException
at javax.mail.internet.MimeUtility.getEncoding(MimeUtility.java:226)
at javax.mail.internet.MimeUtility.getEncoding(MimeUtility.java:299)
at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.updateHeaders(MimeBodyPart.java:1375)
at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.updateHeaders(MimeBodyPart.java:1021)
at javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart.updateHeaders(MimeMultipart.java:419)
at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.updateHeaders(MimeBodyPart.java:1354)
at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.updateHeaders(MimeBodyPart.java:1021)
at javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart.updateHeaders(MimeMultipart.java:419)
at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.updateHeaders(MimeBodyPart.java:1354)
at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.updateHeaders(MimeMessage.java:2107)
at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.saveChanges(MimeMessage.java:2075)
at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.doSend(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:411)
at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:340)
at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:355)
at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:344)
at com.registrationForm.dao.DocumentDaoImpl.generateEmail(DocumentDaoImpl.java:182)
at com.registrationForm.service.DocumentServiceImpl.generateEmail(DocumentServiceImpl.java:45)
at com.registrationForm.controller.DocumentController.saveForm(DocumentController.java:84)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: "D:\images\photo.svg.png", is this true file path?

Answer (score 0):

Which line is 182 in your DAO implementation? I'm guessing the FileSystemResource declaration. Try to split that line like this:

```
File file = new File(/* your file path*/);
if(!file.exists())System.out.println("File doesn't exist");
else { 
  //do stuff
}
```

If you see the message in console your file path is wrong.